# Best way to merge 10+ files into one file

Tags: perl, file, merge

Would writing a script actually be efficient in doing this for that many files (say 15)? Or is there a specific one line command I can use to do such a thing.

For example a script (*in pseudo-code*) I have considered is

```
open file
while $line = <file>
$line = $data1

open file2
while $line = <file2>
$line2 = $data2

print "data1\ndata2\n..."
```

and so forth with the amount of files I need to paste into this new output file.

Comment: By merge, do you mean all of file 1 followed by all of file2 and the files 3... or do mean line 1 of file 1 followed by line 1 of file 2 and so forth?

Comment: Yes! essentially copy and paste all the data in file1, file2... into a new output file. Sorry I didn't clarify that cleanly.

so say
all file1 data
all file2 data
all file 3 data

Comment: What are you trying to do? Merging files line-wise like the Unix `paste` command?

Comment: `cat file1 file2 file3 ... fileN > file_all`?

Comment: so i have some files that contain data that I want to analyze but there are too many separate files. I want to combine all the data in the separate files into one file. To analyze in one go instead of 60.

Comment: @TLP thanks mate! i thought cat wouldn't work for this ~ my mistake.

Comment: @serious You're welcome. I believe it is actually what `cat` was made to do, con**cat**enate files.

Comment: Just in case you weren't aware, you can also use wildcards... `cat file* > BigBoy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are analyzing the files with Perl, you don't have to merge them. Perl's `ARGV` filehandle goes through all of the lines of all of the files you specify on the command line (or really, put in `@ARGV`):

```
while( <ARGV> ) { # special ARGV filehandle
       print "Line is> $_"; # do stuff on the next line, current line in $_
   }
```

It's such a common idiom that it has a shortcut where `ARGV` is the default filehandle:

```
while( <> ) { # special ARGV filehandle is the default
   print "Line is> $_";
   }
```

You'd call the script with all the files you want to go through:

```
$ perl my_program file1 file2 ...
```

When the program gets to the end of one file, it seamlessly goes to the beginning of the next file. Now you don't need on giant file.

There are some interesting tricks. During this process, the current filename is in `$ARGV`. The global line counter is in `$.`:

```
while( <ARGV> ) { # special ARGV filehandle
   print "[$ARGV:$.] Line is> $_";
   }
```

If you want to reset the line counter for each file (probably so look back in individual files), you can close `ARGV` when the current file reaches the end of file (eof):

```
while( <ARGV> ) { # special ARGV filehandle
   print "[$ARGV:$.] Line is> $_";
   close ARGV if eof(ARGV);
   }
```

Perl will automatically re-open `ARGV` for the next file.

Comment: This answer addresses the _intent_ of what the OP is trying to do instead of merely answering the specific question that was asked. The extra stuff about the input line number variable is a little off-topic, but still interesting.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat file1 file2 file3 >combined  # sh or cmd[1]

perl -pe1 file1 file2 file3 >combined  # sh or cmd[1]

copy /y/b file1+file2+file3 combined >nul  # cmd
```

With wildcards:

```
cat file* >combined  # sh

perl -pe1 file* >combined  # sh

perl -MFile::DosGlob=glob -pe"BEGIN { @ARGV = map glob, @ARGV }" file* >combined  # cmd[1]

copy /y/b file* combined >nul  # cmd
```

---

1. Few Windows systems have `cat` or `perl` installed.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you would use this :

```
type file1 file2 file3 > file_all
```

Not sure if there is a maximum number of files that `type` can open or not but this is the Windows equivalent of `cat` (or most similar equivalent)

Comment: That leaves a lot on the screen.

Answer (score -1):

If you were doing this in Windows the following would work:

```
copy /y/b file1 + file2 + file3 + ... fileN file_all >nul
```